# How to migrate the format of a unique non nullable flask model property?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, migration

I would like to change the format of a model property and its name. The property must be unique and not nullable.

It is unclear to me as to how I would go about making the migration for this stuation.

Model before migration:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
        hexdata = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
```

Model after migration:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
        base64data = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
```

Comment: What are you using as a migration tool?

Comment: I am using flask-migrate https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/